# Vertical centering of div only working when JS is linked directly below <body> AND directly above </body>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently using bootstrap and want some text to be centered both vertically and horizontally. I wrote some Javascript that sets the CSS of the text container to absolute position, then calculates the pixels from the top and left in order for the div to be centered correctly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#text-container-container').css({
        height:($(window).height()),
    });
    $('#text-container').css({
        position: 'absolute',
        left: ($(window).width() - $('#text-container').outerWidth())/2,
        top: ($(window).height() - $('#text-container').outerHeight())/2,
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="outer-container" id="text-container-container">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <!--navigation stuff here-->
    </nav>
    <div id="text-container">
      <h1>text</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For some reason, when I load the page, the text is correctly ***vertically*** aligned, but not correctly horizontally aligned. Only when I change the size of my browser window a little does the text go to the correct position (both horizontally and vertically).

I'm also confused because I currently have the link to the Javascript directly before the closing body tag, but when I add a second link to the same JS file directly below the opening body tag, the text somehow aligns correctly on the first try.

Does anyone know what's going on? How can I get it so that it aligns correctly both horizontally and vertically the first time the page loads?

Comment: can you show your HTML code as well please?

Comment: @ZombieChowder Just updated.

Comment: $(document).ready - DOM ready, is not the same as $( window ).on( "load"...:https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ MAYBE (not sure) problem is there... if you have some images, or some heavy-weight content - for calculations, you have to wait till page is loaded completelly... So, try with: $( window ).on( "load", function() { $(window).resize(); })

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out! I have a pretty huge image that spans the entire screen (that's what the text-container-container is for; its background image is very large). Unfortunately, though, when I changed it to window.onload, the same thing happens with the alignment.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you apply a pure `CSS` solution instead, that way no need to bind to the `resize()` function, see this:

```css
#text-container-container, #text-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#main-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container" id="text-container-container">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <!--navigation stuff here-->
    </nav>
    <div id="text-container">
      <h1 id="main-text">text</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For some reason, the same thing happens when I do this; the text doesn't align correctly horizontally until I resize the browser window.

Comment: Remove your scripts as they are no longer needed, and press `ctrl + f5` and see if it remains the same.

Comment: Exactly what I did, unfortunately produces the same result ):

Comment: It seems that you have another `HTML` element that is causing this behavior,  try removing the `nav` for example and see what happens

Comment: The same thing happened when I commented out the nav.

Answer (score 0):

In jquery or javascript you should create a function and call it on ready and on resize :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  center();   
});
$(window).resize(function() {
  center();
});
var center = function() {
  $('#text-container').css({ 
  position : 'absolute',
    left :  (($(window).width()  - $('#text-container').outerWidth() ) / 2),
    top :   (($(window).height() - $('#text-container').outerHeight()) / 2) 
  });
};
```

```css
/* see me */
#text-container {
  border: solid;
  position:absolute;/* <=== needs to be set in CSS too */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer-container" id="text-container-container">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      navigation
    </nav>
    <div id="text-container">
      <h1>text</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Css could easily do it, the easiest would be to use flex i believe, but that was not the question :)